# Merging two rows with rounding their first elemnts

Tags: list-manipulation

Mathematica shows my data in the below style:

```
  lst={....
 {-0.410927, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}}},
 {-0.410927, {{9, 14}, {10, 14}, {13, 7}, {13, 8}}}
  .....}
```

As I copy the first `-0.410927` in another cell, I saw that it is really `-0.41092720756334744` and for the second `-0.410927`, I noticed that it is `-0.4109272075633472` in fact. Regards to the other rows in the above and the below positions of these two shown rows, which are presented by ...., how I merge such two rows and have a result as

```
output=lst={....
 {-0.410927, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}, {9, 14}, {10, 14}, {13, 7}, {13, 8}}}
  .....}
```

In fact, there is no any differences between two `-0.410927`for more digits than `3`.

I have to apply this procedure for other rows considering this fact that all elements have just `3` digits for being important. For instance `1.34267` is not different from `1.34311`.

How can I help Mathematica to merge multi rows with very similar first elements. The similarity is gained after rounding values up to `3` digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lst = { {-0.410927, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}}},
   {-0.41, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}}},
    {-0.45123, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}}},
 {-0.410927, {{9, 14}, {10, 14}, {13, 7}, {13, 8}}}};

Values@GroupBy[lst,  Round[First@#, .001] &, {#[[1, 1]], Join @@ #[[All, 2]]} &]
```

> {{-0.410927, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}, {9, 14}, {10, 
>           14}, {13, 7}, {13, 8}}},
>    {-0.41, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 
>           5}, {15, 6}}},
>   {-0.45123, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 
>       6}}}}

```
Values@GroupBy[lst,  Round[First@#, .01] &, {#[[1, 1]], Join @@ #[[All, 2]]} &]
```

> {{-0.410927, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}, {11, 16}, {12, 
>       16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}, {9, 14}, {10, 14}, {13, 7}, {13, 
>       8}}},
>    {-0.45123, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}}}}

Comment: Thankxx so much. But a problem: once I write the result as `grouped[[1]]` I reach `{{-0.410927, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}}}, {-0.410927, {{9,14}, {10, 14}, {13, 7}, {13, 8}}}}` this out put is not yet merged!

Comment: @Inzo, please see the updated version.

Comment: Amazing and wonderful !!!

Answer (score 3):

```
lst={{-0.410927,{{11,16},{12,16},{15,5},{15,6}}},{-0.41,{{11,16},{12,16},{15,5},{15,6}}},{-0.45123,{{11,16},{12,16},{15,5},{15,6}}},{-0.410927,{{9,14},{10,14},{13,7},{13,8}}}};

{#[[1,1]],Flatten[#[[All,2]],1]}&/@Values[GroupBy[lst,SetPrecision[#[[1]],3]&]]
```

> {{-0.410927, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}, {9, 14}, {10, 
>       14}, {13, 7}, {13, 8}}}, {-0.41, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 
>       5}, {15, 6}}}, {-0.45123, {{11, 16}, {12, 16}, {15, 5}, {15, 6}}}}